# Creating a function for multiple affectation at once in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm currently completing an project for school.
How would I proceed if I were to write a function named `inputfunction()` that would work as follow:

```
var1, coordinates = inputfunction()
"enter var1": 0
"enter coordinates" (x,y): 0,1
>>> print(var1)
0
>>> print(coordinates)
[0, 1]
```

I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried in an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the two different values as a tuple.

```
>>> def inputfunction() -> tuple[int, list[int]]:
...     return (
...         int(input('"enter var1": ')),
...         [int(n) for n in input('"enter coordinates" (x,y): ').split(",")]
...     )
...
>>> var1, coordinates = inputfunction()
"enter var1": 0
"enter coordinates" (x,y): 0,1
>>> print(var1)
0
>>> print(coordinates)
[0, 1]
```